# Error Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, xml

I am writing a  new record to xml file with to item , A English word and a Hebrew word.

But the line 
 `$newWord->appendChild($prop.$new_line);` 
causes this  Error 
**"Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string"**

the parameter **$new_line** equal to `$new_line =  "\n";`.

what I miss here thx ?

my code are:

```
<?php

  /*$wordH=$_GET['varHeb'];
  $wordE=$_GET['varEng'];*/
    $wordH="newhebWord";
    $wordE="newengWord";
  $new_line =  "\n";

$doc='';

        if(!$doc)
        {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            // we want a nice output
            $doc->formatOutput = true;
            $doc->load('Dictionary_user.xml');
        }
        $Dictionary_user = $doc->documentElement;

        $newWord = $doc->createElement('newWord');



        $prop = $doc->createElement('Heb', $wordH);
        $newWord->appendChild($prop.$new_line);
        $prop = $doc->createElement('Eng',$wordE);
        $newWord->appendChild($prop.$new_line);


        $Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore($newWord,$Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0));
        header("Content-type: text/xml");

        $doc->save("Dictionary_user.xml");
    echo $doc->saveXML();


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to append a newline, you are dealing with a real data structure (A [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) not a string.

Comment: ok and if  i want to add new line so the file will look nice what I shell i do ? , it is import to me!